# How to minimize $f(x,y,z)$ on a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the minimization of $$f(x,y,z) = (x-\frac{y}{2})^2 + \frac{3}{4}(y-2)^2 +z^2 -3$$ on the set $$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2\leq1\}$$

I'm trying to use the first and second order necessary conditions ($\nabla f \cdot v \geq 0$ and $v^T\nabla^2f v\geq 0$ for feasible $v$) to identify minimum points.

I think I've narrowed down the set of feasible $v$ to $v=\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix}$ such that $xu+yv <0$.

And I was able to show that $\nabla^2f(x,y,z)$ is positive definite (determinant of all leading minors are strictly positive).

However, I can't figure out how to generate a system of equations to actually identify any "critical" points.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I would try at first without the condition $$x^2+y^2\le 1$$ to find a minimum. After this use the condition $$x^2+y^2=1$$

Comment: Splitting the cases this way was a huge help! Figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We need to look at first at the "interior points" s.t. $x^2+y^2<1$ by the condition $\nabla f=0$.

I've found no critical interior points.

Then we need to check the points $x^2+y^2=1$ using directly that condition.

That should lead to the minimization of $g(x,y)=xy+\frac32 y$ under the given condition.